# Get results with like from 2 different tables and append them together

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the debtors additional address with a specific id.

**debtors**

```
id hnr place      name
1  22  Amsterdam  companyname
2  26  Enschede   anotherCompany
```

**aditional_debtor**

```
id debtors_id hnr place 
1  1          12  Almelo
```

**Result when I select on like debtors.name %companyname%**

```
hnr debtors.id  place       name
22  1           Amsterdam   companyname
12  1           Almelo      companyname
```

My query till now:

```
SELECT * FROM debtors d where d.name LIKE '%companyname%';
```

But how can I join the other table to get the additional addresses and the "default" address from the debtors table (The default address must be the first row in the result set).

Comment: You can easily find resources about join even I dont see in your example any join, have you tried already something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use union and inner join

```
 select  d.hnr, d.place, d.name
 from debtors as d
 d.name LIKE '%companyname%'
 union 
 select  a.hnr, a.place, c.name
 from aditional_debtor as a 
 inner join debtors as c on a.debtors_id = c.id
 and  c.name LIKE '%companyname%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with union all and join (close to @Prdp solution but I prefer a join)

```
select hnr, place, name 
FROM debtors d 
where id =1
UNION ALL
select ad.hnr, ad.place, d.name
FROM debtors d join aditional_debtor ad on d.id = ad.debtors_id
where d.id =1
```